# Getting part of an image with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm doing a final project in MATLAB on "License Plate Correlation". For now the user selects the plate with ROI function, afterwards I want to get only the plate. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using the ROI function, use getPosition on the handle. This gives you the vector [x_min y_min width height]. You can then use this to get your sub image.

```
imshow(I,[])
h = imrect;
cord = getPosition(h);
Sub_I = I(cord(2):cord(2)+cord(4),cord(1):cord(1)+cord(3));
```

Comment: hey thanks for your answer but i get this error: "Warning: Integer operands are required for colon operator when used
as index" do you know what does it mean? and another question what this line does Sub_I = I(cord(2):cord(2)+cord(4),cord(1):cord(1)+cord(3));

Comment: I believe you need to round off the values in `cord` so that they are integers.

Comment: @michael: You can use functions like [ROUND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/round.html), [CEIL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ceil.html), [FLOOR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/floor.html), and [FIX](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fix.html). This is assuming you've plotted your image versus the pixel indices (i.e. the x-axis goes from 1 to `size(img,2)` and the y-axis goes from 1 to `size(img,1)`).

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific. If you want to read in an image you can use the imread(filename, format) function which returns a m by n array. There is a 3rd dimension depending on the format of the image. Then you can subset this array as desired.

More details, see: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imread.html

Comment: i'm already use imread, but i want to know if there is an option to get only the ROI for further work?